# Is it the local way to say " I played a set of Go " or "I played a game of Go"?

Tags: phrases

Can anyone help me understand how to express like

> A set of or two sets of Go game.

I am not sure

1. If 'a set of' is correct?
2. If not, how to correctly express that.
3. In this sentence, is 'Go game' used correctly?

Comment: Is "set" a technical term in Go, like it is in tennis?

Comment: @DJClayworth: Based on a lot of searches, it appears not to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "set" has many meanings. In sports such as tennis, players play a number of *games* that go to make up a *set*; several *sets* make up a *match*. But, to the best of my knowledge, Go is not played like that - you just play a game of Go (like a game of Chess).

To add to the confusion: a "set" can mean "the things required for" - so "a Go set" might mean "the board and all of the pieces needed to play a game of Go with".

So, to answer your questions:

1. No - while it's not grammatically incorrect, that's not how games of Go are usually described in English.
2. Just use "game of Go" - for example, "a game or two of Go", or "one or two games of Go".
3. No. When referring to the game in general, you can say "Go", "the game of Go", "the game Go" but not "*Go game".

Comment: Thank you so so much for the details for my questions, I really appreicate your help!!!!